# Softmax output returning only ones and zeros?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

my convolutional neural network is returning only ones and zeros on softmax output (out1), anyone knows why?

```py
def build(self):
   inp = Input(self.obs_shape)
   conv0 = Conv2D(32, 2, 1, padding="same", activation = "relu")(inp)
   drop0 = MaxPool2D((2,2))(conv0)
   conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, 2, padding="same", activation = "relu")(drop0)
   drop1 = MaxPool2D((2,2))(conv1)
   flat = Flatten()(drop1)
   hid0 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(flat)
   hid1 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(hid0)
   hid = Dense(128, activation='relu')(hid1)
   out1 = Dense(self.action_count, activation='softmax')(hid)
   out2 = Dense(1, activation='linear')(hid)

   model = Model(inputs = [inp], outputs = [out1, out2])
   model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr = self.lr),
                 loss = [self.actor_loss, "mse"])
   return model

def actor_loss(self, y_actual, y_pred):
   actions = tf.cast(y_actual[:, 0], tf.int32)
   returns = y_actual[:, 1]
   mask = tf.one_hot(actions, self.action_count)
   logps = tf.math.log(tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, mask) + 1e-3)

   entropy = -tf.math.reduce_sum(y_pred * tf.math.log(y_pred))

   return -tf.math.reduce_sum(logps * returns) - 0.0001*entropy
```

Comment: is there a problem with `tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy`?

Comment: no, but this was the way i found to be able to use the returns how i wanted

Answer (score 0):

model = Model(inputs = [inp], outputs = [out1, out2])
look at above， there only two output.
so, you function `build` was lock the number of output,
so only get 1 or 0 ;

in one word :you need change your models

sorry ,my english is bad .